# How to find proper checkbox locator

Tags: java, selenium, checkbox

I am writing an automatic test  in Selenium and I have a problem with the locator. The website address: https://talixo.pl/register/?next=/. I can't find the right locator for the last three check boxes. Depending on which locator I use, I get an error 'element not interactable or checkbox is ticked but in the new tab opens the page which is under the link "Read more". I haven't this problem with checkbox without "Read more" link Please help!

```
public void clickDiscountsCheckBox(){
        WebElement discountsCheckBox = driver
                                       .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"id_terms_0\"]"));
        discountsCheckBox.click();
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
>     (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Comment: Why are you using XPath to locate an element by just the ID? Why not use `By.id("id_terms_0")`? Also, did you try waiting for clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.This should work.

```
driver.get("https://talixo.pl/register/?next=/");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            List<WebElement> listOfElements = 
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='label-body']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
for (int i=0; i<listOfElements.size();i++){
               executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",listOfElements.get(i));               
              }
```

Please let me know if this work.

Comment: This should click 3 ‘Read more’ check boxes.

Comment: Great! Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: I know you can’t vote me now.When you get a chance please vote me so that i’ll get more interest to resolve query in this foram.

Comment: I didn't know. In the future i will.

Comment: another perspective +1

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is a bad practice and should not be used. You also should avoid using JSE to click checkboxes when they can be clicked by normal means. When you use JSE to interact with the page, you need to be aware that you are no longer behaving as a user. JSE can click or otherwise interact with the page in ways that no user can... click invisible or obscured elements, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the provided URL and observed that the last three checkboxes to click on is "::before" which is a pseudo element. Have you tried JavascriptExecutor? You can try using CSSSelector to identify the element.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately it also does not work :(